# Capturing stdout breaks in pytest

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

Annoyingly, somebody at my company has written a library full of functions that write data to stdout. I need to capture and use that data, so I've written this.

```py
def capture_output(f):
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout = StringIO()
    f()
    output = sys.stdout.getvalue()
    sys.stdout.close()
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout
    return output
```

**Edit:** this is not for testing. I need to call a method that prints a bunch of stuff to stdout and get that data as a string (without actually printing it). That is the purpose of the `capture_output` method. I cannot use `capsys` because this is business logic, not test logic.

Here is my unit test for this.

```py
def test_capture_output(self):
    output = temp_logger.capture_output(lambda: print('Hello'))
    assert output == 'Hello\n'
```

All is well (the test passes) so long as I call pytest like this:

```
pytest path/to/test.py
```

but if I call it like this:

```
pytest
```

which runs all of our tests, my test breaks.

```
______________________________________________________________________________ TestTempLogger.test_capture_output ______________________________________________________________________________

self = <test_temp_logger.TestTempLogger testMethod=test_capture_output>

    def test_capture_output(self):
        output = temp_logger.capture_output(lambda: print('Hello'))
>       assert output == 'Hello\n'
E       AssertionError: assert '' == 'Hello\n'
E         + Hello

ppt/tests/tools/FIOLauncher/dependencies/test_temp_logger.py:35: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello
```

I assume it has something to do with the way pytest captures data written to stdout, but I don't understand why it would behave differently depending on how I call it. I also haven't been able to find any workaround for this.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

I'm using pytest 4.6.10 (the latest I have access to) and python 2.7.18 (unfortunately).

Comment: pytest has `capsys` fixture which already does this.

Comment: *"...that write data to stdout"* Well, that's the purpose of stdout.

Comment: @wim +1, just use the fixture; that's [what it's for](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) and there's no benefit from trying to figure out exactly how the attempt to hand-roll a solution interferes with the built-in one.

Comment: Can you show how the tests break? I assume that something is not reset correctly, but don't know what it is. BTW, it would be better to use `try/finally` in your function to ensure that `stdout` is always restored. @wim - the question is about testing a function that redirects `stdout`, not about doing it in the test.

Comment: @wim the purpose of `capture_stdout` is not for testing. I need to get the output of a function which prints to stdout as a string as part of my business logic. But I have a test to make sure it works, and that's what's breaking.

Comment: Well you had better create a reproducible example then.  As it stands your test code has undefined variable `temp_logger`.

Comment: @wim `temp_logger` is the package that `capture_output` is a part of. If you'd like to reproduce this you can simply remove it.

Comment: The `self` in your test suggests it lives in a wider test class with setup and teardown. I can not reproduce your issue with a plain old test function, the test passes.

Comment: @wim it is in a test class but there is no setup or teardown. It also passes for me unless I call it with `pytest` alone (which runs all of the other tests we have as well). I don't know what sort of factors might cause this to bug out in that case.

Comment: Then it is due to some code in one of the other tests, which you haven't shown here. I doubt anybody will be able to help you without seeing the wider context of what the rest of the test suite does that is creating/modifying some mutable state. You'll just need to pare it down until the culprit is found.

Comment: @wim you're correct of course. I found the problem and posted it as an answer. So very dumb. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Hah.  And this is why we use patch (so the mock is undone when the test tears down)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was another test that had this line.

```py
sys.modules['sys'] = MagicMock()
```

***sigh***

and here's the kicker, the tests work just fine without it.